# Problemas nas Resources do Laravel 5.4 dentro de Groups

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com problemas ao tentar acessar algumas rotas que vem de um resource (**products**), ela está dentro de um group, segue o meu código:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['web', 'auth'],
    'prefix' => Config::get('shop.admin.url') . '/products',
    'namespace' => 'LaraShop\Products\Http\Controllers',
    'as' => 'products'
], function()
{
    Route::resource('/', 'ProductsController');
});
```

Rotas geradas:

```
| POST      | admin/products         | store   | LaraShop\Products\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@store   | auth
| GET|HEAD  | admin/products         | index   | LaraShop\Products\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@index   | auth
| GET|HEAD  | admin/products/create  | create  | LaraShop\Products\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@create  | auth
| DELETE    | admin/products/{}      | destroy | LaraShop\Products\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@destroy | auth
| PUT|PATCH | admin/products/{}      | update  | LaraShop\Products\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@update  | auth
| GET|HEAD  | admin/products/{}      | show    | LaraShop\Products\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@show    | auth
| GET|HEAD  | admin/products/{}/edit | edit    | LaraShop\Products\Http\Controllers\ProductsController@edit    | auth
```

Ao acessar a rota `admin/products/1/edit` ele retorna erro 404.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Seu controller `LaraShop\Products\Http\Controllers\ProductsController` possui a função `edit`? Tente colocar rum `return 'ok';`para ver se está chegando no Controller...

Comment: Não está chegando no controller, porém ao retirar o resource do group, funciona normalmente.

Comment: E se usar `Route::get('/{id}/edit', 'ProductsController');` dentro de seu group, funciona? Se funcionar dentro do grupo e não funcionar fora, veja se está logado e se no seu controller está usando auth...

Comment: A melhor forma que encontrei foi usar o resource fora e os middleware dentro do controller.

Comment: está vindo assim mesmo `admin/products/{}` dentro das chaves não tem nada???

Answer (score 0):

A rotas [`resources`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers) seguem uma nomenclatura assim:

Primeiro parametro é ***nome da rota*** e o segundo a classe `controller`, no seu caso se colocou uma barra, ou seja, a raiz do site, está conflitando e também o conceito está errado, se não pode criar uma rota assim direta na raiz, só em raros casos onde isso vai ser necessário, então, no lugar da barra coloque "`products`" como exemplificado abaixo:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['web', 'auth'],
    'prefix' => Config::get('shop.admin.url') . '/products',
    'namespace' => 'LaraShop\Products\Http\Controllers',
    'as' => 'products'
], function()
{
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
});
```

isso vai solucionar o seu problema de não encontrar a rota `admin/products` e na hora de imprimir a tabela pelo comando `php artisan route:list` observe que dentro da chaves tem um texto, não pode vir vazia se não sua rota está com problemas, exemplo correto:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                             |                  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/products                | products.index   |
|        | POST      | admin/products                | products.store   |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/products/create         | products.create  |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/products/{product}      | products.show    |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/products/{product}      | products.update  |
|        | DELETE    | admin/products/{product}      | products.destroy |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/products/{product}/edit | products.edit    |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------+------------------+
```

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: Ainda assim não funciona, dessa maneira nada funciona.

Comment: @Raank problema deve ser local seu porque deve ter rota se chocando essa resposta foi testada, se.pode colocar todas as rotas na pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

A solução simples para o caso é:

**route.php**

```
Route::resource('admin/products', '\LaraShop\Products\Http\Controllers\ProductsController', [
    'as' => 'admin'
]);
```

**ProductsController.php**

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new ProductsController instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // defaults middlewares
        $this->middleware(['web', 'auth']);
    }

}
```

A maneira mais simples e, na minha opinião, a melhor maneira semanticamente falando.